# How can I import data into elasticsearch by sending a file in post request in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, http-post, httpurlconnection

Currently I am using following cmd to import data into elasticsearch

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @required.json
```

[ElasticSearch Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Now I am creating a java console application and I need to send this file in a post request. I am able to do this using SoapUI i.e. attaching a file with header

> Content-Type: text/javascript

Doing this request from SOAPUI is successful and data is loaded.

---

I have looked into how to do a post request and I have got to following code. So my questions are :

1. How would we attach a file to the request ?
2. If file attachment is not possible, what is other possible solution ?

   ```
   URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9200/index/_bulk/");
   HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
   httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
   httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/javascript"); // (or text/plain)
   httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
   OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());

   out.write(...filedata...); // <------ How to Put file data in output stream ?

   out.flush();
   out.close();
   ```

Comment: Are you saying this code works? What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ShireResident I update the question.

Comment: what's an elastic search?

Comment: @Patrick it should be read as one word - https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Comment: thanks man. Let me look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to write file contents to output**

```
//out.write(...filedata...); // <------ How to Put file data in output stream ?

// Create a path to your file
Path path = Paths.get("D:/TEMP/bulk.json"); // <------ your file name

// Open a BufferedReader to your file - change CharSet if necessary
BufferedReader fReader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.defaultCharset());

String data = null;
// Read each line, append "\n" to it as required by Bulk API and write it to the server
while ((data = fReader.readLine()) != null) {
    out.write(data + "\n"); // <------ Put each line in output stream
    out.flush();            // <------ You may do this outside the loop once
}

out.close();
```

Note: *There are multiple ways of writing file contents to an outputstream. I have just specified one. You may explore others.*

**bulk.json**

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "string", "_id" : "10" } }
{ "field1" : "value10" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "string", "_id" : "20" } }
{ "field1" : "value20" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "string", "_id" : "30" } }
{ "field1" : "value30" }
```

**Test**

```
http://localhost:9200/test/string/10
{"_index":"test","_type":"string","_id":"10","_version":3,"found":true,"_source":{ "field1" : "value10" }}
```

Also, since your client is Java, have you considered using the ElasticSearch Java Client API? I don't know it well but it should support Bulk requests. Look at the client.bulk(BulkRequest) method.

Comment: Thanks @ShireResident. It works for small data. I tried this with larger data, i get java heap exception. But this give give some idea how to handle this. I think I would send post request in batches like 1000 lines at a time.